# How to get customer shipping country code to generate shipping rates in Cartthrob for that specific country?

Tags: cartthrob, ee, shipping

Presently I only ship within the UK and now wish to extend this to Europe. Shipping is by location and weight thresholds, and I have configured the requisite shipping prices. I have entered the country codes into my_locales and the payment gateway. How do I capture the customer's shipping county at the point of purchase so the shipping calculations will be accurate when they view basket?
Using Cartthrob 3.01

Answer (score 0):

The location/weight threshold shipping settings screen gives you a couple of fields to map your shipping country field (a primary and a fallback) so that CT knows which country settings to use. So, during any action that interacts with the cart (add_to_cart/checkout etc), the user can specify the country via an input/select element with the field's short name in the `name` attribute.